# Coppia minima nell'italiano regionale

Tags: regional, pronunciation

Solo alcune varianti di italiano regionale possiedono le sette vocali dell'italiano standard (/a/, /e/, /ɛ/, /i/, /o/, /ɔ/, /u/):

> Negli [italiani regionali](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/italiano-regionale_(Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano)/) sono documentati sia sistemi con sette fonemi (eptavocalici) sia con cinque (pentavocalici).  I sistemi eptavocalici hanno una distribuzione delle vocali semichiuse e semiaperte differente rispetto allo standard di base fiorentina: sono localizzati nell’Italia centrale, in Campania, in Basilicata, nel Molise, nel Veneto, nel Trentino. I sistemi con cinque fonemi possono avere anche sette vocali fonetiche, tuttavia il timbro semichiuso e semiaperto è esclusivamente condizionato dal contesto, come in Lombardia, Piemonte, Emilia Romagna, Liguria, Puglia. Le varietà con il vocalismo pentavocalico si collocano soprattutto nell’Italia meridionale estrema (Sicilia, parte della Calabria, Salento) e in Sardegna.
>
> (Enciclopedia dell'italiano, [*Vocali chiuse e aperte*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/chiuse-e-aperte-vocali_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) di Silvia Calamai)

Una coppia minima famosa per le vocali /e/ ed /ɛ/ in italiano standard è data da *pésca/pèsca*. Questa coppia minima però non è valida dovunque sia presente un sistema eptavocalico. Ad esempio nel nord-est d'Italia entrambe le parole sono realizzate come /'peska/.

> **Q** Esiste una coppia minima per le vocali /e/ ed /ɛ/ che sia valida su tutte la zone d'Italia dove le vocali sono fonologicamente distinte?

**EDIT:** Una coppia minima per /e/ ed /ɛ/ valida nel veneziano, ma non in italiano standard è *se/sé*, realizzati come /'se/ e /'sɛ/ rispettivamente. In italiano standard entrambe le parole sono realizzate come /se/, some dimostra la grafia stessa di *sé*.

Comment: Per curiosità, qual è una coppia minima /e/-/ɛ/ valida solo nel Nordest (o in parte di esso)?

Comment: @DaG Non lo so! Già questa potrebbe essere una parziale risposta alla domanda... Le vocali /e/ ed /ɛ/ sono percepite come completamente distinte dai parlanti (beh, da me almeno), ma non riesco a pensare ad una coppia minima...

Comment: "Legge" dal verbo "leggere" e "legge" sostantivo? Veramente non so in quali regioni d'Italia sono pronunciate diversamente.

Comment: @Charo Io realizzo entrambi come /'lɛdʒ:e/

Comment: @DenisNardin:   :(

Comment: @DaG Ah ne ho una: *se* e *sé* (realizzati come /'se/ e /'sɛ/ rispettivamente). Almeno, secondo il dizionario di ortografia e pronunzia della rai sono entrambi realizzati come /'se/ in italiano standard.

Comment: Io ho tentato di far percepire a dei torinesi la differenza /e/-/ɛ/ con "io /e/ te" e "lui /ɛ/ bello", ma sembra che non posseggano questa distinzione. Forse, però, questa potrebbe essere la coppia minima che cerchi...

Comment: @LinuxBlanket Questa è eccellente! Nel mio angolino di Veneto almeno questa distinzione esiste. L'unico problema è che la congiunzione *e* è raramente accentata. Che ne dici di scriverla come risposta?

Answer (score 2):

Al momento non riesco a trovare delle fonti, ma credo che una coppia minima /e/-/ɛ/ possa essere composta da **"e"** come congiunzione ed **"è"** come copula. In Italia centrale, Campania e, direi, anche Sicilia (contrariamente alla fonte citata) questa differenza è certamente presente.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su ItalianSE!!

Comment: @abarisone Grazie! (*benvenuta, tra l'altro ;) )

Comment: È possibile che in Sicilia vari. Una volta ho passato una sera a cercare senza successo di far sentire la differenza tra *e* aperta ed *e* chiusa ad una persona di Palermo.